# Docker Compose Postgres Container connection refused from hosting machine

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I have the following definition of docker-compose file with postgres image that I want to run and connect to it from **hosting** machine of my PC, but I'm getting `Connection Refused localhost:5432` all the time. I realize that container has to be run on host network driver, but network mode doesn't solve this problem. What I'm doing wrong?

I run this with `docker-compose -f [file] up` on `Windows 10 with Docker for Desktop`

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  database:
      image: postgres:10.6
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=p0stgr@s
        - POSTGRES_DB=eagle_eye_local
      network_mode: host
```

When I run the same container with the following command it works:

```
docker container run --name postgres10.6 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=p0stgr@s -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e  POSTGRES_DB=eagle_eye_local -p 5432:5432 postgres:10.6
```

Comment: Are you talking about docker for Mac or docker for windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are not running natively on linux but use some Docker for Desktop. Then the short answer is: Remove the `network_mode: host` and the compose setup will work the same way your docker run command works.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  database:
      image: postgres:10.6
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=p0stgr@s
        - POSTGRES_DB=eagle_eye_local
```

The two examples you provided are not really equal even though they can lead to some similar results when run on a real linux host (similar in a way that on a linux host you will be able to access the postgres instance via `localhost:5432` on the host machine).

If you run the given compose file on Docker for Desktop (Mac or Windows) you must keep in mind that in this case there is a VM running your containers and all commands are passed into that VM. If you don't use `network_mode: host` Docker will (1) expose the port correctly on the VM and (2) have some proxy process in place on your host machine (mac/windows) to forward the traffic into the VM. This basically doesn't work when you start the container with `network_mode: host`.

You can verify the established mapping when running `docker ps` under the `Ports` column. This will be empty if you run with `network_mode: host`.

For some more details see the discussions in [the docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/should-docker-run-net-host-work/14215/15).

Comment: I've updated my question with platform - it's Windows 10 with Docker for Desktop. I will check your answer at home. Thanks

Comment: All right. I'm pretty sure the one line change will fix your issues. Could reproduce it also on my Mac which uses basically the same concept.