# Unable to run pytest from host using db in docker container: OperationalError(connection to server at (127.0.0.1) port 5433 failed: Connection refused

Tags: docker-compose, sqlalchemy, database-connection, fastapi

I'm running an application written in FastAPI using SQLAlchemy 2 and psycopg2, and using docker-compose and 2 postgres containers: one for development and one for automated testing.

I basically tried to dockerize the [following application](https://github.com/rhoboro/async-fastapi-sqlalchemy): following the README, the testing works perfectly, but somewhere along the way I screwed up.

Background: accessing the dev db through the backend server works flawlessly. However, when I try to run pytest in PyCharm that's configured to run using an interpreter based off Docker, I encounter the following error:

```
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
        exc_tb     = <traceback object at 0x1127fab80>
        exc_type   = <class 'psycopg2.OperationalError'>
        exc_value  = OperationalError('connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"\n')
        self       = <sqlalchemy.util.langhelpers.safe_reraise object at 0x1127f8280>
        traceback  = None
        type_      = None
        value      = None
```

#### My complete directory structure:

```
├── README.md
├── backend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── api
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── local.env
│   │   └── test.env
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models
│   ├── requirements.lock
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── api
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── guests
│   │   │       ├── __init.py__
│   │   │       ├── __pycache__
│   │   │       │   └── test_views.cpython-311-pytest-7.4.0.pyc
│   │   │       └── test_views.py
│   │   ├── conftest.py
│   │   ├── test_main.py
│   │   └── utils.py
│   └── utils
├── db.password.txt
├── docker-compose.yml
├── pyproject.toml
```

#### Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=fastapi_traefik
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=fastapi_traefik
      - APP_CONFIG_FILE=local
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; cd backend; echo "RUNNING ALEMBIC MIGRATIONS"; alembic upgrade head; cd ..; uvicorn backend.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --reload'
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    secrets:
      - db_password
    networks:
      - dock-db-test

  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    container_name: dev-db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=fastapi_traefik
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=fastapi_traefik
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U fastapi_traefik" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    secrets:
      - db_password
    networks:
      - dock-db-test

  test_db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    container_name: test-db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=inclasstoday
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=inclasstoday1
      - POSTGRES_DB=student-data_test
      - APP_CONFIG_FILE=test
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD="trust"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_test:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U inclasstoday -D student-data_test" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - dock-db-test
    command: -p 5433


volumes:
  postgres_data:
  postgres_data_test:


secrets:
  db_password:
    file: db.password.txt

networks:
  dock-db-test:
    external: false
    name: dock-db-test
```

#### Local.env

```
DB_URI=postgresql+asyncpg://fastapi_traefik:password@db:5432/fastapi_traefik
ECHO_SQL=False
```

#### Test.env

```
DB_URI=postgresql+asyncpg://inclasstoday:inclasstoday1@localhost:5433/student-data_test
ECHO_SQL=False
```

#### Conftest.py

```
from typing import AsyncGenerator, Generator

import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event, text
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, SessionTransaction

from backend.db import get_session
from backend.main import app
from backend.models.base import Base
from backend.config import settings


@pytest.fixture
async def ac() -> AsyncGenerator:
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="https://test") as c:
        yield c


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def setup_db() -> Generator:
    engine = create_engine(f"{settings.DB_URI.replace('+asyncpg', '')}")
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(text("commit"))
    try:
        conn.execute(text("drop database test"))
    except SQLAlchemyError:
        pass
    finally:
        conn.close()

    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(text("commit"))
    conn.execute(text("create database test"))
    conn.close()

    yield

    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(text("commit"))
    try:
        conn.execute(text("drop database test"))
    except SQLAlchemyError:
        pass
    conn.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def setup_test_db(setup_db: Generator) -> Generator:
    engine = create_engine(f"{settings.DB_URI.replace('+asyncpg', '')}/test")

    with engine.begin():
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        yield
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)


@pytest.fixture
async def session() -> AsyncGenerator:
    # https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5811#issuecomment-756269881
    async_engine = create_async_engine(f"{settings.DB_URI}/test")
    async with async_engine.connect() as conn:
        await conn.begin()
        await conn.begin_nested()
        AsyncSessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(
            autocommit=False,
            autoflush=False,
            bind=conn,
            future=True,
        )

        async_session = AsyncSessionLocal()

        @event.listens_for(async_session.sync_session, "after_transaction_end")
        def end_savepoint(session: Session, transaction: SessionTransaction) -> None:
            if conn.closed:
                return
            if not conn.in_nested_transaction():
                if conn.sync_connection:
                    conn.sync_connection.begin_nested()

        def test_get_session() -> Generator:
            try:
                yield AsyncSessionLocal
            except SQLAlchemyError:
                pass

        app.dependency_overrides[get_session] = test_get_session

        yield async_session
        await async_session.close()
        await conn.rollback()
```

#### config.py

```
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict
import os
from pathlib import Path

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    DB_URI: str
    ECHO_SQL: bool

    #https: // stackoverflow.com / questions / 9271464 / what - does - the - file - variable - mean - do
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_file=Path(__file__).parent / f"config/{os.environ['APP_CONFIG_FILE']}.env",
        case_sensitive=True,
    )


settings = Settings.model_validate({})
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.lock ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.lock
COPY . .
```

I've tried running from the command line as well, and after loading my venv and running the following:

`python -m pytest backend` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named)

I get the following errors:

```
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
        cargs      = ()
        cparams    = {'dbname': 'student-data_test', 'host': 'localhost', 'password': 'inclasstoday1', 'port': 5433, ...}
        self       = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGDialect_psycopg2 object at 0x110d4bd50>
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:122: in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
E   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5433 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
E       This probably means the server terminated abnormally
E       before or while processing the request
```

Have tried multiple different solutions, including only running the test db without the dev db running and mapping the port to 5432 (didn't work). Also tried using the test docker service's name instead of localhost in the DB_URI string, didn't work. Tried referencing the port as 5432 while referencing the docker service's name, didn't work. Have read through [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192148/fastapi-and-postgresql-in-docker-compose-file-connection-error) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55457069/how-to-fix-operationalerror-psycopg2-operationalerror-server-closed-the-conn) [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842362/docker-compose-postgres-container-connection-refused-from-hosting-machine) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842362/docker-compose-postgres-container-connection-refused-from-hosting-machine), but haven't found the solution yet.

[image: docker ps of running containers. Observe that the test container is correctly listening at port 5433]

docker ps of running containers. Observe that the test container is correctly listening at port 5433

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you running the `pytest` command inside a container or on your local computer? What happens if you try to connect using `psql` from localhost/the container to database container? You should also wrap your `ports` definition as a string, but it shouldn't make a difference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810789/quotes-on-docker-compose-yml-ports-make-any-difference

Comment: I've done both: I run them in Pycharm where I have an interpreter configured in the following way: (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#config-docker)- I'm not sure in what Docker environment exactly this is configured, but I've added a picture above to show the services at runtime.

I've also run it from my local machine using pytest and get the same error. However, I am able to connect to the db by `docker exec -it test-db sh` into the psql container and then `psql -p 5433 -U inclasstoday -d student-data_test`. Added more context pics above.

Comment: A quick `telnet` to the port should show whether anything is actually picking up the connection from your localhost; since you can connect with `-p 5433` inside your container, it seems like it has changed ports internally as well (this is generally not necessary, as you can keep using `5432` internally, and just expose it as `5433` to avoid complicating internal configuration in the container.

Comment: Yup, `telnet` to the `localhost 5432` and `localhost 5433` both get picked up. I removed the `command: psql -p 5433` line and remapped ports `5433:5432`, and  I can still `telnet` to each port.

Comment: In that case - does `psql` on your _localhost_ work for connecting to the database (not inside the container)? And are you then running pytest on your _localhost_ and not inside the container? (inside the container the hostname would not be localhost, but `test_db`) (underscores in hostnames are a story by itself, but my initial guess would be that it shouldn't affect anything in this case)

Comment: Just finally figured this out- it turns out there was an error in my pytest setup, and your suggestion regarding using `telnet` gave me the confidence that the port was available to my host computer, and to look in the pytest setup. Thanks for your help!